# Solve a Boundary Value Problem with weird answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

$$y''+2y'-8y=0$$

Where $0\leq x\leq2$, $y(0)=0$, and $y(2)=0$

At first I tried to solve it just like a normal differential equation and I got $y=Ae^{-4x}+Be^{2x}$

But when I input the condition $y(0)=0$, and $y(2)=0$ it became $y(x)=0$

Am I wrong? I feel it is weird. Or there is something special about $0\leq x\leq2$ ?

Thank you

Comment: You are correct. $y(x)$ identically zero is a valid solution

Comment: Robert is right. Moreover, Mathematics is full of Weird creatures! :))))

Answer (score 1):

The "responsible" is not the considered interval, but the choosen boundary values.
Consider a more general problem
$$y''+2y'-8y=0\\ y(0)=c, \; y(2)=d$$ with $0\leq x \leq 2, \; c,d\in \mathbb{R}.$
The constants $A,B$ in the general solution $$y=Ae^{-4x}+Be^{2x}$$ satisfy
$$A=\frac{d-ce^{4}}{e^{-8}-e^4},\; B=c-A.$$

If $c=d=0,$ as it is in your case, then $A=B=0.$